# question about the definition of the exterior square of a group

Tags: group-theory

On groupprops, one definition they give of the [exterior square of a group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exterior_square_of_a_group) is as follows:

Let $G$ be a group, and let $F$ be the free group on the generating set $G\times G$. For any central extension $E$ of $G$, the commutator map $G\times G\rightarrow [E,E]$ given by sending $(g_1,g_2)\mapsto[\tilde{g_1},\tilde{g_2}]$, where $\tilde{g_1},\tilde{g_2}$ are lifts of $g_1,g_2$ to $E$, which is not well defined, but their commutator is, since the kernel of $E\rightarrow G$ is central. For every central extension $E$, this map induces a surjective homomorphism $\Omega_E : F\twoheadrightarrow [E,E]$. Then, they define the exterior square $G\wedge G$ of $G$ to be the quotient of $F$ by the intersection of all kernels of all maps $\Omega_E$.

My question is - For any central extension $E\rightarrow G$, isn't $[E,E]\cong [G,G]$, so really the maps $\Omega_E$ are all essentially the same map $F\twoheadrightarrow [G,G]$, so all the kernels are the same?

What am I missing?

EDIT: Okay, so given any commutator $[g_1,g_2]\in [G,G]$, this defines a unique commutator $[\tilde{g_1},\tilde{g_2}]\in [E,E]$. Does this map define an injective homomorphism $[G,G]\rightarrow [E,E]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed map $[G,G] \to [E,E]$ isn't well defined.  It's possible that $[g_1, g_2] = [h_1, h_2]$, but the lifts $[\tilde{g_1}, \tilde{g_2}] \ne  [\tilde{h_1}, \tilde{h_2}]$.

Consider the case $E = Q_8$ (the quaternion group).  The center of $E$ is $\{1, -1\}$ and the quotient $G := E/Z(E) \cong C_2 \times C_2$.  The map $E \to G$ is the quotient map. Since $G$ is abelian, we have $[G,G] = 1$ i.e., no matter what we choose $g_1$ and $g_2$ to be, we get $[g_1, g_2] = 1$.  But when we lift we can get anything in $[E,E] = \{1, -1\}$, so the map $[G,G] \to [E,E]$ isn't well defined.